# How to send form From HTTPS page to HTTP link in action whithout raising browser security alert

Tags: forms, http, firefox, browser, https

I'm setting up a web page for a new hotspot system with social login. No  everythings works fine But when user click on the login button the browser (firefox) show the Security Alert box because the local hotspot url is in http but the website in https.
How can i prevent the security alert to be triggered ?

Sorry for my english.
Thanks.

Comment: I believe this is a browser question and not related to programming.

Comment: Thanks, yes is a browser question, i want to know if with programming it can be prevent from showing or auto validate when it appear.

Answer (score 0):

At the end i have to put my hotspot link in https.